# Compiler complains on the third parameter of the library function sort

Tags: c++

```
bool compare(vector<int> &i1, vector<int> &i2)
    {
        return (i1[0] < i2[0]);
    }
vector<vector<int>> &intervals = {{1,3},{2,6},{8,10},{15,18}}; 
sort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), compare);
```

What I want to do is sorting intervals based on the start time. But when I run the codes, the compiler will complain on the function sort that `"error: reference to non-static member function must be called"` Could anyone explain why it doesn't work?

Comment: Is `compare` a member function? Providing a [mcve] would make your question much easier to answer.

Comment: It doesn't work because, as the message says, `compare` is a non-static member function. It can be anything function-like except that. That is, a free function, or a static member, or an object with a suitable `operator()` overload, …)

Comment: Use a lambda instead of a standalone comparison function.  Problem solved.